# Multiple instances of the ConversationalRetrievalChain (LangChain)

Tags: python, flask, langchain

I'm interested in learning how to create multiple instances of the ConversationalRetrievalChain in my service. Specifically, I want to have a distinct ConversationalRetrievalChain for each database, for example. Has anyone already tried this? Thanks

Create services for each database.